# Maven - Spring RequestMapping 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I've seen a lot of this questions in SO and i've tried their solutions but they haven't worked for me so I'll post this one. Basically I'm just setting up a project and trying to get my RequestMapping to work, just to return a string. So this is my code

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ve.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenDWP</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>  
  <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>  
</properties> 

<dependencies>
  <!--  Spring -->
  <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!--  CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet API, JSTL --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- MySQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSONDoc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsondoc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.15</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsondoc-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.15</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.15</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AngularSpring</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="ve.com" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="ve.com.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="documentationController" class="org.jsondoc.springmvc.controller.JSONDocController">
    <constructor-arg name="version" value="1.0"/>
    <constructor-arg name="basePath" value="http://localhost:4848/mavenDWP/api"/>
    <constructor-arg name="packages">
    <list>
    <value>ve.com</value>
    </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

LinkController

```
package ve.com.controller;

import org.jsondoc.core.annotation.ApiMethod;
import org.jsondoc.core.annotation.ApiResponseObject;  
import org.jsondoc.core.annotation.ApiVersion;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@ApiVersion(since="1.0")
@RequestMapping("/show") 
public class LinkController {

    @Autowired
    private StockService stockService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/hello")
    public String showHello() {
        return "hello";
    }        
}
```

Ok Basically that's my code.. Still i browse to http://localhost:4848/mavenDWP/api/show/hello and i just get a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: Cut your example down to size.  No one wants to wade through a 100 lines of pom.xml.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you remove `jasondoc`?

Comment: still haven't been able to solve it. and i can't remove jsondoc since i need it for some annotations

Answer (score 1):

Add @ResponseBody annotation. Every time when you return something that is not a build in class such as ModelAndView you need to use this annotation. See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody).

As an advice, try to use a Map even if you have a little amount of data to send to client. A map will be converted to JSON and can be easily accesed.

Answer (score 0):

All is well, Try jsut to remove the space beteween     *servlet-class*   and org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in the web.xml

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

Good luck